# Are homotopic maps with identical boundary values homotopic through a boundary preserving homotopy?

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M,N$ be smooth $d$ dimensional manifolds. Suppose $f_0,f_1:M \to N$ are homotopic, and that $f_0|_{\partial M}=f_1|_{\partial M}$.

Is there a homotopy $f_t$ such that $f_0|_{\partial M}=f_t|_{\partial M}$ for all $t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily.

As a counterexample, take $M,N=S^1\times[0,1],\;f_0=id,\;f_1(\theta,t)=(\theta+2\pi t,t)$.

**Edit:** We show that there is no homotopy between the above $f_0,f_1,$ that restricts to the identity on the boundary at any time.  Define two paths $\gamma_0,\gamma_1:[0,1]\to S^1\times[0,1]$ by
$$
\gamma_0(t)=(0,t),\quad\gamma_1(t)=(2\pi t,t).
$$
If the above $f_0,f_1,$ are homotopic without moving the boundary then, in particular, the paths $\gamma_0,\gamma_1$ can be extended to a smooth family of paths $\gamma_t:[0,1]\to S^1\times[0,1]$ such that $\gamma_t(0)=(0,0)$ and $\gamma_t(1)=(0,1)$ for every $t$. Now, for every $t$, write
$$
I(t):=\int_{\gamma_t}d\theta.
$$
Then $I(t)$ changes continuously with $t$ and only admits values in $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $I(0)=I(1)$, which is a contradiction.

**Remark:** This example is the first step in the definition of *Dehn twists*. Hence, I'm pretty sure you can find more explanations and intuitions for that across the internet or in any textbook about mapping class groups.

Comment: Thanks. I might be slow today, but can you please say why there is no homotopy respecting the boundary?

Comment: @AsafShachar I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. BTW, I am curious about a slightly modified version of this question: Suppose $f,g$ are homotopic, and coincide on an *open subset* $U \subseteq \partial M$. Now, is there a homotopy which is constant along an open subset of $\partial M$ (perhaps smaller than $U$) ,or at least constant on the boundary? Of course, I can extend the maps in your example to be the identity outside $[0,1]$-but this won't be smooth. I wonder if there is an example in the smooth category.

Comment: Also, I wonder if there is an example (to either version of the problem) where the target has no boundary.